# Google Play Store Error Security Implicit Pending Intent is not resolved even after trying suggestion from google doc

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

**We have already used FLAG_IMMUTABLE with pending intent for Version>=23 . Here are all the dependencies we are using in our project, even after updating the firebase, one signal library used for sending/receiving notification, google play store is still giving the pending intent security error on uploading the apk.
Following are the dependencies used and the code for notification.
PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE. Can Anyone suggest what could be the possible solution**

```
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.12"
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.3'
    implementation 'androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:17.0.1'
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.12"
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:20.1.1'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:20.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:21.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'


    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation('com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.4.0') {
        exclude module: 'glide'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:21.0.1'

    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'


    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.99.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.truizlop.sectionedrecyclerview:library:1.2.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$anko_version"
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.2.6'
    implementation "com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.2"
    implementation 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:3.2.0'


    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:4.7.0'
    //for inApp Update
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.moengage:moe-android-sdk:11.0.04'
    implementation 'com.moengage:rich-notification:2.0.01'
    implementation("com.moengage:geofence:1.0.00")
    implementation("com.moengage:push-amp-plus:3.0.01")

    // implementation 'com.github.mreram:showcaseview:1.1'

    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.12"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.12"

    testDebugImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.19.0'


    //    Add Zxing library to generate barcode
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    implementation project(':tokenautocomplete')
    implementation project(':linkpreviewlibrary')

    //flaoting action button
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'

    implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0"
    implementation "com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'

    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.32.2"
    implementation 'com.github.douglasjunior:android-simple-tooltip:0.2.2'
```

````
 private void sendNotification(String notificationTitle, String notificationBody, Bitmap bitmap, Intent intent, Intent backIntent) {
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent;

        if (backIntent != null) {
            backIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            Intent[] intents = new Intent[]{backIntent, intent};
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(this, notificationId++, intents, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE );
            } else {
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(this, notificationId++, intents, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            }
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, notificationId++, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
            } else {
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, notificationId++, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            }
        }

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;


        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        String name = "gramophone_channel";
        String id = "gramophone_channel_1"; // The user-visible name of the channel.
        String description = "gramophone_first_channel"; // The user-visible description of the channel.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = null;
            if (notificationManager != null) {
                mChannel = notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(id);
            }
            if (mChannel == null) {
                mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
                mChannel.setDescription(description);
                mChannel.enableVibration(true);
                mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
                if (notificationManager != null) {
                    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
                }
            }

            notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)   //Automatically delete the notification
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.leaf_logo) //Notification icon
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                    .setContentText(notificationBody)
                    .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri);

        } else {
            notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)   //Automatically delete the notification
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.leaf_logo) //Notification icon
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                    .setContentText(notificationBody)
                    .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri);

        }
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.notify(notificationId++ /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can add `FLAG_IMMUTABLE` always. You don't need to make this check for the API level in your code.

See if that helps. If not, there is probably something in one of your dependent libraries that is causing the problem and you will need to contact the library vendor and get an update for the library.